# Is it safe to clone a type-erased Arc via raw pointer?

Tags: rust, unsafe, type-erasure, raw-pointer

I'm in a situation where I'm working with data wrapped in an [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html), and I sometimes end up using [`into_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.into_raw) to get the raw pointer to the underlying data. My use case also calls for type-erasure, so the raw pointer often gets cast to a `*const c_void`, then cast back to the appropriate concrete type when re-constructing the `Arc`.

I've run into a situation where it would be useful to be able to clone the `Arc` without needing to know the concrete type of the underlying data. As I understand it, it should be safe to reconstruct the `Arc` with a dummy type solely for the purpose of calling `clone`, so long as I never actually dereference the data. So, for example, this should be safe:

```rust
pub unsafe fn clone_raw(handle: *const c_void) -> *const c_void {
    let original = Arc::from_raw(handle);
    let copy = original.clone();
    mem::forget(original);
    Arc::into_raw(copy)
}
```

Is there anything that I'm missing that would make this actually unsafe? Also, I assume the answer would apply to `Rc` as well, but if there are any differences please let me know!

Comment: `clone` increments the refcount, and `from_raw`, `into_raw` and `mem::forget` do not touch it, so the effect of calling `clone_raw` is just to increase the refcount by 1. I assume this is just a dummy example (i.e. in your real code you would do something other than `mem::forget` with `original`)?

Comment: (I think this is safe in the sense of "very unlikely to do anything bad", I'm just trying to make sure I'm not overlooking something weird)

Comment: yeah your example is poor, this is safe but unlikely to do what you want. In fact, what do you want ?

Comment: In the example I gave, I need to do `mem::forget(original)` so that it isn't dropped at the end of the function, which would decrement the ref count. The other option would be to do `Arc::into_raw(original)` instead, as shown [in this example](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/is-it-safe-to-clone-a-type-erased-arc-via-raw-pointer/36723/2?u=excaliburhissheath).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost always unsafe.

An `Arc<T>` is just a pointer to a heap-allocated struct which roughly looks like

```
struct ArcInner<T: ?Sized> {
    strong: atomic::AtomicUsize,
    weak: atomic::AtomicUsize,
    data: T,  // You get a raw pointer to this element
}
```

`into_raw()` gives you a pointer to the `data` element. The implementation of `Arc::from_raw()` takes such a pointer, *assumes* that it's a pointer to the `data`-element in an `ArcInner<T>`, walks back in memory and *assumes* to find an `ArcInner<T>` there. This assumption depends on the memory-layout of `T`, specifically it's alignment and therefore it's exact placement in `ArcInner`.

If you call `into_raw()` on an `Arc<U>` and then call `from_raw()` as if it was an `Arc<V>` where `U` and `V` differ in alignment, the offset-calculation of where `U`/`V` is in `ArcInner` will be wrong and the call to `.clone()` will corrupt the data structure. *Dereferencing `T` is therefore not required to trigger memory unsafety*.

In practice, this might not be a problem: Since `data` is the third element after two `usize`-elements, most `T` will probably be aligned the same way. However, if the stdlib-implementation changes or you end up compiling for a platform where this assumption is wrong, reconstructing an `Arc<V>::from_raw` that was created by an `Arc<U>` where the memory layout of `V` and `U` is different will be unsafe and crash.

---

Update:

Having thought about it some more I downgrade my vote from "might be safe, but cringy" to "most likely unsafe" because I can always do

```
#[repr(align(32))]
struct Foo;

let foo = Arc::new(Foo);
```

In this example `Foo` will be aligned to 32 bytes, making `ArcInner<Foo>` 32 bytes in size (8+8+16+0) while a `ArcInner<()>` is just 16 bytes (8+8+0+0). Since there is no way to tell what the alignment of `T` is after the type has been erased, there is no way to reconstruct a valid `Arc`.

There is an escape hatch that might be safe in practice: By wrapping `T` into another `Box`, the layout of `ArcInner<T>` is always the same. In order to force this upon any user, you can do something like

```
struct ArcBox<T>(Arc<Box<T>>)
```

and implement `Deref` on that. Using `ArcBox` instead of `Arc` forces the memory layout of `ArcInner` to always be the same, because `T` is behind another pointer. This, however, means that all access to `T` requires a double dereference, which might badly affect performance.

Comment: Great answer. I added the `T: ?Sized` bound to your reproduction of `ArcInner` because that is what ensures that `data` will always be at the end of the layout of `ArcInner` -- without it, or `repr(C)`, Rust would be able to place `data` wherever it wanted (which would mean all bets were off, even for a `T` less strictly aligned than `usize`).

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer! I suspected this wouldn't work the way I wanted, but your answer makes it clear why.

Comment: How does rust find the arc that it previously `mem::forget` about?

Comment: @user1685095 Every `Arc` is essentially just a `std::ptr::NonNull<ArcInner<T>>`. So as long as there is at least one such pointer left and as long as the reference counter in `ArcInner<T>` matches the number of `Arc<T>` that will be dropped, other `Arc<T>` can be re-constructed and everything will be fine. Only the very last `Arc<T>` to be dropped also deallocates the `ArcInner<T>`.

Comment: @user2722968 l don't see how that answers my question. I asked how previously allocated `Arc` is found in `Arc::from_raw`.

Comment: @user1685095, the `Arc` is not allocated at all, it's just a pointer stored in a register or on the stack. When an `Arc` is dropped normally, it deferences its inner pointer to `ArcInner` (which is allocated on the heap), decrements the reference count stored there, and deallocates the `ArcInner` if the reference count reaches zero (that is, if it was the last `Arc`). When you `forget()` an `Arc`, the reference count never decrements and `Arc` simply vanishes.

Comment: @user1685095  It might be helpful to realize that ALL `Arc` referencing the same object are actually simply the same pointer. It's the ownership mechanics where one owner (`self`) equates to one increment/decrement of the counter that makes everything work. There is no need to "find" the "previous" `Arc`. If you `from_raw()`, you need to guarantee that the reference count is correct (actually: one to large). Given that, the "new" `Arc` is just another copy of the same pointer, whose destructor will decrement the reference count in the future.